# Efficient way to transfer data between 2 clients over TCP with intermediate server

Tags: c, tcp, pthreads, client-server

This is for educational purpose (University assignment).

I need to write a client-server programs in C for Linux. (I already have that part. A client connects to the server, it sends and receive files without a problem...).

When a client connects to the server, it sends the server a list of files on the client. So the server has a list of all the files on it's clients.

A client A can request from the server a file "test.txt", the server knows that the file is on client B, and the file should be transferred from B to A. I'm trying to think about the best way of doing this.

1. recv from B into a buffer, and immediatly send() the buffer to A?
2. recv() the whole file from B and save it on server ,then send it
   to A?

My programs should support this behavior:
if A asks a file from B, and then C asks a file from B, C should NOT wait until the transfer A<-->B will end. And this is where I get stuck.

Thank you very much!!

Edit: My server is using threads: whenever a new client is connecting, a new thread is opened to serve it. My client, at this moment, does not use threads (this can be changed).

Comment: So, what have you done so far to try to solve the problem. Bear in mind that we're not here to write code for you or solve all your school assignment. You have to do the work - that's how you learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do several transfers at once using sockets you have two options:

**Blocking sockets and threads**

This is the way you've written your server. The problem with threads is that they can lead to bugs that are rather hard to debug. Combine that with network bugs that in themselves can be rather hard to debug and you have a potential nightmarish debugging session on your hands.

**Non-blocking sockets and select()**

This way doesn't need threads, instead it uses select() to see which sockets have data waiting to be read. Combine that with some loops and you can transfer several files concurrently. Setting sockets to be non-blocking is easy, using correct can be slightly trickier but weighted against the potential for thread + network bugs this is the way I personally prefer to write network code.

Regarding your actual problem; I would suggest something like this:

```
Client A connects to server S. You need to bind the local side for the next step.
A also opens another socket for data transfer on the next port upwards.
S sends file list to A. How you build up the file list I leave to you.
A requests file F from S.
S checks which client has F.
S sends "send F to A on port X" to B. You can check which remote port is used, and then you know which port to send the file on.
B recieves and executes the command.
```

Comment: hmmm... thanks dutt. I'm going to read all about that. I'm surprised threads are not needed (at all? not even on the server?) I have completed all of your "steps" above up to step 5 (include), but I need to think no about step 2 (A also opens another socket). Some googeling might help me... I'll post on my successes and failures. Thanks.

Comment: Think about why you are using threads. Is it to handle several sockets at once? If so then you don't have to use threads, you can but you don't have to.

Comment: So what I actually need to do is to find out how select() really works with several sockets, without threads..? Also, how this "A also opens another socket for data transfer on the next port upwards." is possible?

Comment: Just do what you are doing again but bind it on the next port.

Comment: I've managed to get rid of the threads, and use select(). Thanks for the tip. So now my program work OK, but I still haven't implemented the file-sending-thing.
I managed to discover the client port (from the client app) using getsockname(), and now I want to bind the next port upwards- my question is- should I create a new socket(), bind() it and only when I get a request from the server use connect() to fulfill the request?

Comment: My thought was that the second port on A is listening for incoming file transfers. socket(), bind(), listen().

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect 2 sockets per client, so you gonna have 4 sockets like this :

```
1 A <-> C
2 B <-> C 
3 A <-> C <-> B 4
```

So you will have to use socket 1 and 2 to transfer file just between client A and Server C (socket1)  and between client B and Server C (socket 2).

Then you will have to developp a bridge in server C using socket 3 and 4 to transfer data from A to B.

A multithreading solution should work, I guess !

Comment: Mats- sure, I'm not asking you to write to code for me. I just want your help in thinking (-: (crowd sourcing or something like that). Joze- Thanks, I'm thinking on this direction. Does it mean my client should also use threads? I mean, my client should listen to incoming request from the server and for user input as well...

Comment: Yes, for sure, if you want multiple transfer in the same time !

Comment: I want to elaborate your answer: when my client recognize a server request, and starts a new thread to handle the request, should it create a new socket to the server? should the server create another socket to that client? I'm really confused...

Comment: If "A" wants a file so create a new socket to "C". "C" knows that the file is in "B" so "C" connects a socket to "B". Then C has to do the bridge between A and B (When it received data from the socket B  it directly send it to socket A).

Answer (score 0):

What I've got so far:
Server is running only with select().
Client has a socket in listen() mode- call it dataSocket (on top of it's regular socket).
If a client A want a file, it tells the server the file name. The server finds the user with the file, and making a connet() to the dataSocket. (I managed to implement that).

Small files are transferred without a problem. Big files fails.

I think it's because something is wrong with my client.
I've implemented the client with a select() function, and if it finds some one doing a connect() it opens a new thread and serves the request. But something there is wrong..
The code is like this:

```
FD_SET(globalSocket,&origin);
FD_SET(dataSocket,&origin);
FD_SET(STDIN,&origin); //#define STDIN 0
while(1)
{
 readfds=origin;
 select(fdmax+1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,NULL);
 for(i=0;...)
  {
   if(FD_ISSET(i,&readfds)
   {
    if(i==STDIN)
     // get user input
    if(i==dataSocket)
     {
      printf("someone wants a file from me");
      pthread_create(...);
     }
   }
  }
}
```

One problem that I saw is when I do my first request of the file, it prints the line "someone want a file from me" 2 or 3 times, but only one thread is created.
And when I try to send a large file, I do get some of it, but then a "Connection reset by peer" pops out...

I hope somebody here will be able to answer my not-so-good-explained question.
Thank you.